# Highcharts: How to make line touch left + right sides

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to make this line touch the left + right edges, instead of the padding/margin highlighted in red here:
[image: sample]

I have tried everything from minPadding, maxPadding, margin, spacing, groupPadding to pointPadding...

Here are my chart options:

```
{
chart: {
  margin: 0,
  spacing: [0,0,0,0]
},
title: { text: '' },
xAxis: {
  labels: { enabled: false },
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0
},
yAxis: {
  title: { text: '' },
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  labels: { enabled: false },
  offset: 0
},
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointPadding: 0
  },
},
series: [{
  data: [12, 8, 43, 35, 20, 90, 100, 110],
  type: 'line',
  showInLegend: false,
  marker: { enabled: false }
}],
tooltip: { enabled: false },
credits: { enabled: false }
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thx!

Comment: Are you sure that your config doesn't work? Seems that there is no unwanted space on my device: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uftrwng6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solutions work with this. Did you try it?

```
{
   chart: {
  
   "marginLeft": 0,
   "marginRight": 0,
   "spacing": [0,0,0,0]
  },
//....other configs
}
```

if not check following link solves you problem
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40852

Comment: The link you provided had the solution I was looking for - Thx!